# Modelling simple bacteria growth

Tags: python

so i'm trying to model a simple bacteria growth. The rules are as follow:

1. Every one hour, the bacteria doubles
2. Every 3 hours, the population of the bacteria drops 25%

```
def bakteri(init,hour):
  a = init*2
  b = a*2
  for t in range (1,hour):
    if t % 3 == 0:
      a = a - a*0.25
      yield a
      a, b = b, b*2
    else:
      a = a
      yield a
      a, b=b, b*2

a = [int(i) for i in bakteri(50,10)]
print(a)
```

I've tried to make it but the result shows
[100, 200, 300, 800, 1600, 2400, 6400, 12800, 19200]

when it should be [100, 200, 300, 600, 1200, 1800, 3600, 7200, 10800, 21600]

Can anyone points out the mistake? Thank you so much

Comment: Try debugging and see at which step the value deviated from the expected.

Comment: Shouldn't the third value be 150 and not 300, because it dropped by 25%?

Comment: @fractal397 25% of 400 is 100. 400-100=300

Comment: So it doubled and immediately dropped? hmm okay

Comment: Why does `b` exist? It doesn't do anything `a` couldn't do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not here to debug your code for you. What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? There seem to be two different problems: 1) the numbers are wrong, and 2) there aren't enough of them. For the first problem, do you know how to debug your code? If not, try using a single-stepper like [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/). Meanwhile, the second problem is a dead-simple off-by-one error with `range`. Just do `hour+1`.

Comment: @wjandrea I thought `b` is there to replace the value of `a`?

Comment: @Owen But why? Like I said, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is rather clunky. What do the `a` and `b` variables even do? Just use the `init` variable itself, like so:

```
def bakteri(init, hour):
    for i in range(1, hour + 1):
        init *= 2     # Same as init = init * 2
        if i % 3 == 0:
            init = 0.75 * init
        yield init
```

This is a very simple problem with a very simple solution. It looks as though you've been overcomplicating it a **lot** more that necessary.
All you need to do is:

1. Make the population double every iteration
2. If the iteration number is divisible by 3, set it to 75% of itself

In that order.

Output

```
>>> print([int(i) for i in bakteri(50, 10)])
[100, 200, 300, 600, 1200, 1800, 3600, 7200, 10800]
```

Comment: Simpler: `init *= 0.75`.

Comment: @wjandrea That's true, but the OP doesn't seem to be familiar with that notation yet, so I used it only once so they could see what it did.

Comment: In the second line, it needs to be ```range(1, hour+1)```, with the +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with:

```
a = a - a*0.25
yield a
a, b = b, b*2
```

Notice that here, even though a changed, disrupting the pattern, b has not been adjusted.
`b = a*2` was up before this change happened. So you didn't double the bacteria after a 0.25 decrease, you doubled the original before the decrease, and then carried on with it.

Preserving your original code structure, here's a revised one:

```
def bakteri(init,hour):
  a = init*2
  for t in range (1,hour+1):
    if t % 3 == 0:
      a = a - a*0.25
      b = a*2
      yield a
      a, b = b, b*2
      print(a, b)
    else:
      a = a
      b = a * 2
      yield a
      a, b = b, b*2
      print(a,b)

output = [int(i) for i in bakteri(50,10)]
print(output)
```

You need to have `b = a*2` after you assign a value to a, for both the *if* and the *else* blocks.

Also note that `range(a,b)` stops at b-1. So when you did `for t in range (1, hour)` it only did 1 to 9 instead of 1 to 10.

(I also changed the "a" in the last two lines to "output", it's good to name variables differently to avoid confusion.

With that said, there is a more efficient way to program this. If you keep perfecting your code and learn, with time it'll come to you naturally.

The simpler code:

```
def bakteri(init, hour):
    for i in range(1, hour+1):
        init = init * 2
        if i % 3 == 0:
            init = init * 0.75 # Times 0.75 is the same as decrease by 0.25
        yield init


print([int(i) for i in bakteri(50, 10)])
```